# Как размеры рабочей области заносятся в lParam?

Tags: winapi, c++

```
case WM_SIZE :
    cyClient = HIWORD(lParam);
    return 0;
```

К примеру в этом коде в переменную cyClient заносится высота рабочий области, которая расположена в старшем слове. 
Так вот, что-то я не пойму как эта вся схема с младшим и старшим словом устроена.
За извлечения ширины и высоты отвечают эти два макроса :

```
#define LOWORD(l)           ((WORD)(((DWORD_PTR)(l)) & 0xffff))
#define HIWORD(l)           ((WORD)((((DWORD_PTR)(l)) >> 16) & 0xffff))
```

Их код понятен, но а все остальное нет, потому что не пойму как заносятся высота и ширина в lParam. 
Могли бы вы привести пример кода, который вносит скажем значения ширины 1280 и значения высоты 1024, а потом извлекает любое из них с помощью тех двух макросов?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для заполнения можете юзать такой макрос:

```
LPARAM  lp = MAKELPARAM( 1280, 1024);

#define MAKELONG(a, b) ((LONG)(((WORD)((DWORD_PTR)(a) & 0xffff)) | ((DWORD)((WORD)((DWORD_PTR)(b) & 0xffff))) << 16))

#define MAKELPARAM(l, h) ((LPARAM)(DWORD)MAKELONG(l, h))
```

Чтобы получить значения, делаете так:

```
WORD  width  =  LOWORD(lParam);
WORD  height =  HIWORD(lParam);
```

Определения для типов можете найти [здесь](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: А зачем все эти проверки или что там делается, если работает и так :
    #define MAKELONG(a, b)      (a) | (b) << 16
Могли бы вы каждый пункт расписать в макросе MAKELONG? То есть в каких случаях нужны те приведения типов и побитовое умножение?